# Expect doesn't recognize command "timeout" in loop

Tags: expect

I have an expect script to check login status, if console showing `"poplar login",` script will send username (no password) and wait 180s for system ready.
Once system ready it will check is the console showing `"root@poplar"` if yes, it will break and send `success` message. If not, expect will be timeout and go back to `"poplar login"`

my script

```
set timeout 2 
expect {
            "poplar login" {
               send "root\r";
               sleep 180; send "\r" ;
               send "\r" ;
               exp_continue
            }
            "root@poplar"
            timeout { send "\r" ; exp_continue }
} 

send_user "login success!\n"
```

Somehow the timeout is always not read by expect and the log is like follow

```
 expect: does"\r\n\u001b[r\u001b[m\u001b[2J\u001b[H\u001b[?7h\u001b[?1;4;6l
 \u001b[?1049h\u001b[4l\u001b[?1h\u001b=\u001b[0m\u001b(B\u001b[1;70r\u001b[H
 \u001b[2J\u001b[H\u001b[2J"(spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "poplar login"? no
 "root@poplar"? no 
 " send "\r" ; exp_continue "? no
 expect: timed out
 login success! 
 send: sending "reboot\r" to { exp5 }
```

Please assist, thanks

Comment: u mentioned `"poplar@login"` but in your code it's `"poplar login"`.

Comment: @pynexj sorry it's a typo, amended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
"root@poplar"
timeout { send "\r" ; exp_continue }
```

to

```
"root@poplar" {}
timeout { send "\r" ; exp_continue }
```

or it would be handled as

```
"root@poplar" timeout
{ send "\r" ; exp_continue }
```

That's why you see the debug message

```
" send "\r" ; exp_continue "? no
```

because the part `{ send "\r" ; exp_continue }` is handled as a PATTERN.